# How to apply a function to a range in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I tried to play with the example data from clojuredocs.org.

```
;; Data
(def scenes [{:subject "Frankie"
              :action "say"
              :object "relax"}

         {:subject "Lucy"
          :action "loves"
          :object "Clojure"}

         {:subject "Rich"
          :action "tries"
          :object "a new conditioner"}])

(defn play [scenes n]
  "Play a scene"
  (->>
   scenes
   (#(get % n))
   ((juxt :subject :action :object))
   (interpose " ")
   (apply str)))
```

The `play` function works fine:

```
my-stuff.core> (play scenes 0)
"Frankie say relax"
my-stuff.core> (play scenes 1)
"Lucy loves Clojure"
my-stuff.core> (play scenes 2)
"Rich tries a new conditioner"
```

This `play-all` function doesn't work:

```
(defn play-all [scenes]
  "Play all the scenes"
  (let [x (count scenes)]
    (for [n (range x)]
      (map play scenes n ))))
```

How to correct this `play-all` function, i.e. how to apply the play function to the range of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` iterates over a collection (or several collections) to produce a sequence.
`for` build a sequence from a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension).
In your case you can use either one *or* the other.

In terms of decomposition, it would make sens to have actually a function that plays *one* scene :

```
(defn play-one [scene]
  "Play a scene"
  (->>
   scene
   ((juxt :subject :action :object))
   (interpose " ")
   (apply str)))
```

Then playing the nth can use precedent definition:

```
(defn play-nth [scenes n]
  "Play the n(th) scene"
  (->
   scenes
   (#(get % n))
   play-one))
```

And you have several ways to play all the scenes:

```
(defn play-all-map1 [scenes]
  "Play all the scenes"
 (map (partial play-nth scenes) (range (count scenes))))
```

But you can really simplify since you don't need `range` because `scenes` can be treated as a sequence (assuming you are not interested in the index):

```
(defn play-all-map2 [scenes]
  "Play all the scenes with map"
  (map play-one scenes))
```

And with `for`:

```
(defn play-all-for [scenes]
  "Play all the scenes with for"
  (for [scene scenes]
    (play-one scene)))
```

Comment: You can define `(def play-nth (comp play nth))`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need both `for` *and* `map`.

With only `for`:

```
user=> (defn play-all [scenes]
  #_=>   "Play all the scenes"
  #_=>   (let [x (count scenes)]
  #_=>     (for [n (range x)]
  #_=>       (play scenes n ))))
#'user/play-all
user=> (play-all scenes)
("Frankie say relax" "Lucy loves Clojure" "Rich tries a new conditioner")
```

and with only `map`:

```
user=> (defn play-all [scenes]
  #_=>   "Play all the scenes"
  #_=>   (let [x (count scenes)]
  #_=>     (map #(play scenes %1) (range x))))
#'user/play-all
user=> (play-all scenes)
("Frankie say relax" "Lucy loves Clojure" "Rich tries a new conditioner")
```

(I prefer the latter.)

Edit: If you like `->>`, this is even better:

```
user=> (defn play-all [scenes]
  #_=>   "Play all the scenes"
  #_=>   (->> scenes
  #_=>     (count)
  #_=>     (range)
  #_=>     (map #(play scenes %))))
#'user/play-all
user=> (play-all scenes)
("Frankie say relax" "Lucy loves Clojure" "Rich tries a new conditioner")
```

Answer (score 0):

Before we do anything with it, your `play` function should deal with a single scene:

```
(defn play [scene]
  "Play a scene"
  (->> scene
   ((juxt :subject :action :object))
   (interpose " ")
   (apply str)))
```

You use it like so:

```
(play (scenes 0))
;"Frankie say relax"
```

... which is no easier or harder than before. But

- it will work with any scene and
- the scenes don't have to be kept in a vector.

It also makes `play-all` simpler:

```
(defn play-all [ss]
  (map play ss))

(play-all scenes)
;("Frankie say relax" "Lucy loves Clojure" "Rich tries a new conditioner")
```

---

I was tempted to replace `((juxt :subject :action :object))` with `vals` in `play`, but we can't rely on the sequence order of the map entries.

Comment: Almost all of this is in [@AbbéRésina answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28780858/1562315), posted as I composed this.